# Equilibrium of a rotating particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, equilibrium

Consider a point like particle rotating in a circle with constant angular velocity. Then there must be a centripetal force ok, now the question is can we say that object in equiliibrium?  If your answer is yes then are you saying that there are no net force acting on the particle?